# Lightbox not working in Chrome, IE ( Coding Mistake)

Tags: jquery, html

Friends

light box not working in Chrome and IE but working for Mozilla. Its a coding problem I think,pls help me with a solution. I have given the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function check(chkbox,srr)
{

    if (chkbox.checked)
    {

        var sre = $('srr');
        $(function() {

            var lightboxHTML = '<div id="overlay"></div>' +
                               '<div id="lightbox">' +
                               '<a href="#" id="exit" onclick = "close2()">Close</a>'  +
                               '<img src='+sre+'/>' + '<p/>' + '</div>';

            $(lightboxHTML).appendTo('body').hide();

            $('#overlay').css('opacity', '0.8');

            //$('img', '#lightbox').attr('src', sre);


            $('#overlay, #lightbox').show();

            event.preventDefault();

        });
    }
}
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function close2()
{

    $(function() {
        $('#lightbox, #overlay').hide();
        event.preventDefault();
     });
}
</script>
```

Comment: If either you or a mod could format the Javascript with "code" tags, it would really help...

Comment: '<img src='+sre+'/>' + '<p/>' + '</div>'; why not 'srr' itself? instead of $ing it to 'sre'

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `$('srr')` should either be `$('#srr')` or `$('.srr')`, as I am guessing `srr` is not a tag name. I'm not sure if this is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to show us how you're using this code.
You're sending in a variable called `srr`, but you're surrounding it with single quotes in your jquery selector.

Your second mistake is trying to use a jquery object as a string for the image source. I don't know what you're expecting your `sre` variable to be, but if you're selecting an image, then you should change your image tag to: `<img src=' + sre.attr("src") + ' />`